# Parsing XML in Powershell Workflow

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to read data from an XML file in a Powershell Workflow. 
In a normal Powershell script, I would load the file into an XML Object: `[xml]$object = Get-Content $xmlPath`. Workflow doesn't seem to like these objects though, and on any checkpoints, fails with the error:

```
The input objects cannot be serialized. Serialized data is required to suspend 
and resume workflows. To resolve the error, verify that the values of all 
variables and parameters are of types that can be serialized.
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidResult: (:) [], SerializationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStatusFailed
```

Does Powershell have another way of parsing XML that meshes well with Workflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations for operations in Workflow, so, some PowerShell code should be put to `InlineScript` to avoid this limitations:

```
workflow Parse-Xml {
    $xmlPath = "...."
    $xml = InlineScript {
       [xml] Get-Content $Using:xmlPath
    }

    $xml
}

Parse-Xml
```